# FormsAuthentication allow acces to all pages

Tags: c#, web-config, forms-authentication

i am trying to implement `FormsAuthentication`, but i get a bit of a strange behaviour.
these are the lines from `web.config` :

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="/contentpages/login.aspx" name="SiteAuth" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" defaultUrl="/" requireSSL="false" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
     <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

So, if i get it right, this should allow all anon users to access the root and the pages under it.

accessing the site main page (http://www.sample.com/) redirects me to the login page for some reason.
if i re-enter the address in the address bar, it takes me to the site homepage as supposed to (with no need to login, i didnt login when i got to the login page, just re-entered the address in the address bar)

Why does this happen?

i hope i made clear what the situation is, if you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Curious, do you get the same behavior when you remove the authorization rule for anonymous users?

Comment: nope, offcourse it will not do the same, since no auth is needed. but it is still interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be seeing this functionality because you are not specifying a location.  Try this out:

```
<location path="your folder">
    <system.web>
    your authorization
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Another issue may be how you are going about granting the rights.  "?" targets all unauthenticated users.  If you are trying to simply grant access to all users, you would be better off with using a "*".

It is also important to make note that these rules are cascading.  So you can add multiple rules to fine tune your access.  For example, if I wanted to grant access to a specific group of users and deny access to everyone else I would use:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="administrators" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: The thing is, i want to allow access to all pages and authorise only two pages. adding the `Location` tag creates a 500 error (even tough i add it in `Configuration` section. also, it still dosent explain the behaviour.

Comment: You should be able to add location path="site root folder" with an allow users="*" and then create another location for each of the pages you want to deny.  It is cascading so each authorization you set up builds on top of the previous one.  I would be interested in seeing the error message you are receiving.  If you view the page from a browser on the server you should be able to get the full error message.

Comment: the error i get is a `dumb` error:
Server Error

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Are you able to get the actual error from the server event log?

Comment: I wonder if this behavior is happening because of an incomplete configuration.  <allow users="?" /> is basically telling the server to only allow users who are missing a forms auth cookie.  If you have been testing the login script you may have a cookie in your cache which would cause the page to deny you.  At the very least, I'd change the ? to a * since from your description you want all anon users to have access to the page.  Then add location tags for the pages you want to require login.